# Rsync Only Different Files with a Checksum?

Tags: macos, command-line, file-transfer, rsync, osx-mavericks

Does anyone know if it's possible to run rsync to transfer all changed/new files in a directory (and its sub-directories) from my local OSX 10.9 machine up to a network share?  The wrench in the plan is that I only want to copy files that have changed, not just different timestamps.  Do I need to run a difference check first?  If so, how do I automate this entire sequence?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `-c` or `--checksume` switch for that. The `rsync(1)` manual page says:

> -c, --checksum              skip based on checksum, not mod-time & size

So this should work as expected:

```
rsync -ac SRC HOST:DEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `rsync -art local-path remote-host:remote-path` might do the trick?